# Variable incorrect in my code

Tags: c

It compiles correctly, but when I run it and input a number it outputs some random string of seven numbers. I have no idea what to do with this.
For example I put in 5 and it gives me 2751724 then I do it again and get 3537324.
I don't know if I have some settings off or what but this seems pretty simple to me.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int number;

    printf("Input number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    printf("Number is: %d \n", &number);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just print number not &number, &number is the adresss in memory where number is

Comment: You can printing  the wrong thing in `printf("Number is: %d \n", &number);`. Hint: what does `&` do here?

Comment: Oh thanks to the both of you. I got the syntax messed up in my head.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but search doesn't find anything since they have all been downvoted to death :)

Comment: when calling any of the scanf family of functions, always check the returned value to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: Please change title from "Variable incorrect in Microsoft Visual Studio" to "Variable incorrect in my code".  You don't know enough to blame the compiler yet.

Comment: Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `&` operator gets the address of a variable in memory (aka a pointer). By using this functions can alter the value of that variable directly without having to return a value. You should read up about pointers and how to use them.

In short, `printf("Number is: %d \n", number)`.

Answer (score 1):

when you do like this:

```
printf("Number is: %d \n", &number);
```

you print the address of number instead of the value of number